# How do I recover my Clash of Clans when switching from Android to iPhone?

Tags: technical-issues, clash-of-clans, ios, android

So I just got an iPhone and Game Center only asks for my Apple ID, which is not connected to my Clash of Clans. However my Clash of Clans was connected through Facebook. Is there anyway to load this on my iPhone?

Comment: If clash of clans was connected to Facebook just log into the same account the same way you originally connected the account

Answer (score 1):

First, press the Cog button.

On the android device, press *this is the old device* and then *what you are linking to* and it should give you a code.

Then you go on the new device and do the same steps, but then hit *this is the new device* and enter that code from the old device.